# FusionCharts error

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I am trying to convert the flash version of the Fusion Charts that I have been using to Javascript.

I imported the FusionCharts.HC.js and FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js as well as the FusionCharts.js and as I was told I put the FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript') line before rendering my charts. something like the following:

```
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
var XMLArray = ...
barChart = new FusionCharts("/sei/static/flash/FCF_StackedBar2D.swf?ChartNoDataText= ", "barChartLarge", 460, 260, 0, 1);

barChart.setDataXML(XMLArray);
barChart.render("barDivBroadcast");
```

Without the setCurrentRenderer its fine and displays what I want in Flash . but when I add that line to change the render, I get the following error

Error: DesignTimeError: #25081843 timelineChart.render Error >> #25081843:IECompatibility() Chart Id is same as a JavaScript variable name. Variable naming error. Please use unique name for chart JS variable, chart-id and container id.

And instead of the chart this error message 'Chart type not supported' appears on screen with a white background.

Can someone help me out here . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are/were using FusionCharts FREE. It will not support JavaScript charts.

However, since you are using the required JS files, it is supposed to work provided you give the corect chart swf files name or chart alias.

Use `StackedBar2D.swf` or  `stackedbar2d` instead of `FCF_StackedBar2D.swf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dispose the fusion chart object like:

```
If FusionCharts(barChartLarge){
       FusionCharts(barChartLarge).dispose();
}
```